# What's the difference between using JSONSerialization and JSONDecoder in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

What's the difference between using JSONSerialization and JSONDecoder in swift, while converting JSON to a swift model? It's seems like they are doing the same job. If they do, then when is which to use?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You should always use `JSONDecoder` because it is better than `JSONSerialization`, which is an Objective-C API. Using Objective-C APIs in Swift just feels a little more awkward than using pure Swift ones, don't you think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple has provided JSONDecoder which is a huge relief in swift4 and onwards. We can decode json in just one line. eg

```
{// sample from quicktype app online
"greeting": "Welcome to quicktype!",
"instructions": [
"Type or paste JSON here",
"Or choose a sample above",
"quicktype will generate code in your",
"chosen language to parse the sample data"
 ]
}
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
let greeting: String
let instructions: [String]
}
//   let welcome = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
```

Here welcome is the struct which is conforming to codable protocol.

If you want to parse **JSON by hand** rather than using **Codable**, iOS has a built-in alternative called JSONSerialization.But i think everybody would like to use JSONDecoder. And also **quicktype creates json model** classes or struct for **u for free**.
Check yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Use JSONDecoder !

If I remember well, JSONDecoder appeared in Xcode 9, with Swift4.
It's cleaner and much more efficient to encode and decode JSON. 
To do so, your Swift Class has to conform to Decodable Protocol.

JSON Serialization is the Old School. (Like Objective-C)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you're creating a model use `JSONDecoder` if not and the data can be used as Foundation type, that is one of: `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSNull` you can live with `JSONSerialization`.

Example:

```swift
private let json = """
{
    "greeting": "Welcome to quicktype!",
    "instructions": [
        "Type or paste JSON here",
        "Or choose a sample above",
        "quicktype will generate code in your",
        "chosen language to parse the sample data"
    ]
}
"""

private func decodeGreeting_v1(data: Data) -> String {
    let welcome: NSDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! NSDictionary
    return welcome["greeting"] as! String
}

private struct Welcome: Codable {
    var greeting: String
    var instructions: [String]
}

private func decodeGreeting_v2(data: Data) -> String {
    let welcome = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
    return welcome.greeting
}

private func decode() {
    let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
    print("JSONDecoder: \(decodeGreeting_v2(data: data!))")
    print("JSONSerialization: \(decodeGreeting_v1(data: data!))")
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The correct answer is: You use the JSONSerialization class to convert JSON to Foundation objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON.
But you can use JSONDecoder only in one way - from JSON to Foundation!